# Trying to boot an arch linux install USB on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017) running macOS Big Sur 11.2.3 results in a black screen

Tags: arch-linux, boot, macintosh, macos

I am trying to install Arch Linux on my MacBook. I've [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to write `archlinux-2021-04.01-x86_64.iso` to a USB stick and as far as I can tell that succeeds. When I go into the startup manager by pressing `Alt`, I select the USB stick, but then all that happens is the screen goes black and does not change. I then have to power down the laptop and power it up again.

However, I've also tried `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso` using the same technique and that *does* boot successfully.

I've also tried some alternative arch installers which do not work:

- [`anarchy-1.3.1-x86_64.iso`](https://anarchyinstaller.gitlab.io/)
- [`zen_installer-2020.05.27-x86_64.iso`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/revenge-installer/)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I then tried different versions of Arch Linux. The screen worked on versions from 2018 and 2019, but the keyboard did not. According to https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux#53, Linux 5.3 added keyboard drivers so the MacBook keyboard worked out of the box, so I knew I had to use a version between then and when the screen stuff broke.

`archlinux-2020.01.01-x86_64.iso` worked perfectly. Once I installed arch, the kernel was updated again and so I got a black screen when I booted. I then tried installing [`rEFInd`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to see if that made a difference, and luckily it fixed the black screen problem.

So my solution to this problem is this:

1. Install `rEFInd`.
2. Install an Arch Linux version after Linux 5.3. Hopefully any version should work as `rEFInd` fixed the black screen issue, but to be extra sure you can try `archlinux-2020.01.01-x86_64.iso`.